# Python - TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, spyder, kaggle

I'm trying to run the following Python script on Spyder Python 3.7. I am very new to python and this is my first time attempting to run a program this complicated:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import matplotlib.image as mpimg
  import numpy as np
  import statsmodels.api as sm
  import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
  import itertools
  matches = pd.read_csv( '/Input/international-football-results-from-1872-to-2017/results 3.csv')

matches.head(2)

matches = matches.astype({'date':'datetime64[ns]'})

print = ( "Then I create a dataframe with some statistics by team like the sum, count and mean of score for each team.")

# create two dataframe for the home and away teams
home = matches[['home_team', 'home_score']].rename(columns={'home_team':'team', 'home_score':'score'})
away = matches[['away_team', 'away_score']].rename(columns={'away_team':'team', 'away_score':'score'})
# merge it into one and removes any corrilation between away and home teams
team_score = home.append(away).reset_index(drop=True)
team_score.head(5)

# make an aggregation of the the score column group by the team
country_info = team_score.groupby('team')['score'].agg(['sum','count','mean']).reset_index()
country_info = country_info.rename(columns={'sum':'numb_goals', 'count':'numb_matches', 'mean':'goal_avg'})
del home, away

means = matches[['home_score','away_score']].mean()
means


def weight_from_tournament(tournament):
    if 'Cup' in tournament or 'Euro' in tournament or 'Copa del Rey' in tournament or 'UEFA' in tournament or 'Copa Libertadores' in tournament or 'Copa America' in tournament:
        return 1;
    else :
        return 100;
# Weight column based on type of tournament
matches.loc[:,'weight'] = matches['tournament'].apply(weight_from_tournament)

# Mpdify weight column based on the date
matches.loc[:,'weight'] = 1 / ((2019 - matches['date'].dt.year.astype('int64'))*matches['weight'])

# Create model data
matches_model_data = pd.concat([matches[['home_team','away_team','home_score','weight']].rename(
            columns={'home_team':'team', 'away_team':'opponent','home_score':'goals'}),
           matches[['away_team','home_team','away_score','weight']].rename(
            columns={'away_team':'team', 'home_team':'opponent','away_score':'goals'})])

#So here using the statsmodels librairies I create my model with a Poisson regression.

poisson_model = smf.glm(formula="goals ~ team + opponent", data=matches_model_data, 
                        family=sm.families.Poisson(), freq_weights=matches_model_data['weight'].values).fit()

print = ("Now it's time to make a function that can return the result of a game, there is some information that we need to know : ")

def get_proba_match(foot_model, team1, team2, max_goals=10):
    # Get the average goal for each team
    t1_goals_avg = foot_model.predict(pd.DataFrame.apply(data={'team': team1, 'opponent': team2}, index=[1])).values[0]
    t2_goals_avg = foot_model.predict(pd.DataFrame.apply(data={'team': team2, 'opponent': team1}, index=[1])).values[0]

    # Get probability of all possible score for each team
    team_pred = [[poisson.pmf(i, team_avg) for i in range(0, max_goals+1)] for team_avg in [t1_goals_avg, t2_goals_avg]]

    # Do the product of the 2 vectors to get the matrix of the match
    match = np.outer(np.array(team_pred[0]), np.array(team_pred[1]))

    # Get the proba for each possible outcome
    t1_wins = np.sum(np.tril(match, -1))
    draw = np.sum(np.diag(match))
    t2_wins = np.sum(np.triu(match, 1))
    result_proba = [t1_wins, draw, t2_wins]

    # Adjust the proba to sum to one
    result_proba =  np.array(result_proba)/ np.array(result_proba).sum(axis=0,keepdims=1)
    team_pred[0] = np.array(team_pred[0])/np.array(team_pred[0]).sum(axis=0,keepdims=1)
    team_pred[1] = np.array(team_pred[1])/np.array(team_pred[1]).sum(axis=0,keepdims=1)
    return result_proba, [np.array(team_pred[0]), np.array(team_pred[1])]


def get_match_result(foot_model, team1, team2, elimination=False, max_draw=50, max_goals=10):
        # Get the proba
        proba, score_proba = get_proba_match(foot_model, team1, team2, max_goals)

        # Get the result, if it's an elimination game we have to be sure the result is not draw
        results = pd.Series([np.random.choice([team1, 'draw', team2], p=proba) for i in range(0,max_draw)]).value_counts()
        result = results.index[0] if not elimination or (elimination and results.index[0] != 'draw') else results.index[1]

        # If the result is not a draw game then we calculate the score of the winner from 1 to the max_goals 
        # and the score of the looser from 0 to the score of the winner
        if (result != 'draw'): 
            i_win, i_loose = (0,1) if result == team1 else (1,0)
            score_proba[i_win] = score_proba[i_win][1:]/score_proba[i_win][1:].sum(axis=0,keepdims=1)
            winner_score = pd.Series([np.random.choice(range(1, max_goals+1), p=score_proba[i_win]) for i in range(0,max_draw)]).value_counts().index[0]
            score_proba[i_loose] = score_proba[i_loose][:winner_score]/score_proba[i_loose][:winner_score].sum(axis=0,keepdims=1)
            looser_score = pd.Series([np.random.choice(range(0, winner_score), p=score_proba[i_loose]) for i in range(0,max_draw)]).value_counts().index[0]
            score = [winner_score, looser_score]
        # If it's a draw then we calculate a score and repeat it twice
        else:
            score = np.repeat(pd.Series([np.random.choice(range(0, max_goals+1), p=score_proba[0]) for i in range(0,max_draw)]).value_counts().index[0],2)
        looser = team2 if result == team1 else team1 if result != 'draw' else 'draw'
        return result, looser, score


    print = ("Now let's try it !")

    print(get_match_result(poisson_model, 'Gabon', 'Togo'))
    print(get_match_result(poisson_model, 'France', 'Togo', elimination=True))
    print(get_match_result(poisson_model, 'Argentina', 'Germany'))
    print(get_match_result(poisson_model, 'Brazil', 'Vatican', max_goals=20))
    print(get_match_result(poisson_model, 'England', 'Morocco'))
    print(get_match_result(poisson_model, 'Iran', 'Japan'))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
print(get_match_result(poisson_model, 'Gabon', 'Togo'))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-72-3287e60bece4>", line 1, in <module>
    print(get_match_result(poisson_model, 'Gabon', 'Togo'))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I have modifyed the script from: https://www.kaggle.com/nathanlauga/which-team-will-win-the-2018-fifa-world-cup

It runs fine if Fork the Notebook and use the Kaggle online console.

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The syntax for print is `print("String to print")`. When you write `print = "String"`, you redefine print to point to a string instead of the print function.

Comment: Also you don't follow a return command with a semicolon (you want `return 1`, not `return 1;`.

Comment: I'll make the suggested changes.

Comment: You guys were right its running smoothly now. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is only on the syntax.

In Python you don't want to express `print = ('something')` because that means that you are assigning a value to a variable called print. Instead you have to do `print('something')`

I hope it helped

Comment: You guys were right its running smoothly now. Thank you !